# Hibernate: projection over entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to obtain a projected entity of an existing entity in Hibernate? For example, I have an entity User with id, version, name, address table.  For some use cases I need all the columns, while for some other use cases I need a subset of them. I know that it is possible to create a new entity, but I would like to know if it is possible to project it as for DTO projection for example.

Thank you

Comment: After posting it I realized, this question does not make sense, just create the new entity and that's it. This can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe creatting 2 DTOs and 2 converters?

Comment: Please rephrase your Answer to be more assertive. It sounds like a question.

Comment: My point was about having an entity which covers all the columns of a particular table and a projection that returns an entity with the selected columns, but still an entity, managed by Hibernate lifecycle. It was for avoiding extracting columns even when they are not used for a particular use case. I suppose that the solution is to create multiple entities, potentially one for each use case, or set all relations as eager (which in any case wont prevent the extraction of non relation columns and still the extraction of the foreign key of each eager relation).